# How do I create an Azure Functions Consumption Plan on Linux with an ARM Template?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Azure Functions Consumption Plan running on Linux [is now GA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#hosting-plan-support).

How can I provision such application with an ARM Template?

Basically, I want [this template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-function-app-create-dynamic/azuredeploy.json) but on Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to create a new Linux Consumption Plan, set the **reserved** property to true for `Microsoft.Web/serverfarms` (see [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-faq#management)):

```
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
        "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
        "name": "[parameters('serverfarms_NorthEuropeLinuxDynamicPlan_name')]",
        "location": "North Europe",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Y1",
            "tier": "Dynamic",
            "size": "Y1",
            "family": "Y",
            "capacity": 0
        },
        "kind": "functionapp",
        "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('serverfarms_NorthEuropeLinuxDynamicPlan_name')]",
            "reserved": true
        }
    },
```

If you rather want to deploy a Function App to a built-in Linux Consumption Plan, set the **kind** property for `Microsoft.Web/sites`:

```
"kind": "functionapp,linux"
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I asked. If you look at the linked template, it creates a new App Service Plan (`Microsoft.Web/serverfarms`) with SKU `Y1/Dynamic`. However, adding `"kind": "functionapp,linux"` doesn't seem to work there: I still get a Windows cluster.

Comment: I added the serverfarm section to my answer.

Comment: Ha, this worked! So what's the magic property to turn the plan into Linux?

Comment: Good question :D. I think its the functionapp,linux hint on the function app (since the app service plan is consumption based)

Comment: It seems to be `"reserved": true` which makes the difference :-O

Comment: Fun fact: `kind: "functionapp,linux"` doesn't seem to be required. It works with just `functionapp`. Should we edit the answer to remove (1)? It is required if one doesn't create there own plan.

Comment: It seems that kind: linux is necessary for Azure Portal user experience

Comment: Are you sure that serverfarm should have functionapp kind?

Answer (score 0):

See this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-infrastructure-as-code#create-a-consumption-plan

Primary this line:

> The Consumption plan cannot be explicitly defined for Linux. It will be created automatically.

Comment: According Martin Brandl answer it could be done. I will create PR to update funtion docs

Answer (score 0):

One simple way I found out during my trial and error is, download the ARM template from the Azure for this purpose and then modify with appropriate naming convention for consumption plan. Then deploy the ARM template to create the function app.

**Steps are as below:**

**Downloading ARM template from Azure:**

Try to create a new function app with Linux consumption plan. At this point in time on GUI, azure does not allow us to select the name for the consumption plan (screenshot below)

[image: Create function app - Linux consumption plan]

Complete other steps (monitoring, tags, etc) and then go to "Review and Create" step. Let the validation pass here. Once this step is done, do not click "Create" button. On the right side down now you can see "Download a template for automation" link. Click this link and download the template. Modify the parameters with the required ones'. Change the Hosting plan name to required name.

**Modify the parameters file and deploy to create function app:**

In Azure, go to "Custom Deployment" blade and then upload both Template and parameters file. Deploy this ARM template. It will easily create the function app with Linux consumption plan with desired naming convention for Consumption plan (dynamic)

Comment: I am not sure if it works with consumption app service plans if we would like to define it explicitly